# $\alpha$ limit and $\omega$ limit subsets of a compact metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $h : X \to X$ be a homomorphism. Is it possible that $$\alpha(x) \cap \omega(x) = \emptyset$$ for all $x \in X$.

In here, $\alpha(x)$ is the $\alpha$ limit of $x$ and $\omega(x)$ is the corresponding $\omega$ limit.

I know both $\alpha$ & $\omega$ limit sets are closed invariant in this case but don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f : \overline{\mathbb{R}} \rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ defined by $f(x)=x+1$.

Comment: I need $X$ to be compact.

Comment: I took $\overline{R}$, i.e. the natural compactification of $\mathbb{R}$ (on which you can define a metric). If you want, take any homeomorphism $h : (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and define $f$ on $[0,1]$ by $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, and if $x \in (0,1)$, then $f(x)=h^{-1}(h(x)+1)$. This is basically the same example.

Comment: What about this?

Define $$R_{\alpha} : S^1 \to S^1$$ to be a circle rotation given by $R_{\alpha}\,(x) = xe^{i\alpha}$.

If $\alpha$ is irrational then for any $x \in S^1$, orbit $O(x)$ is dense in $S^1$. Thus,$\alpha(x) = \omega(x)=S^1$.

Comment: Yes, what you say is correct, but your question is "is it possible ?", isn't it ? So I gave you an example where $\alpha(x) \cap \omega(x) = \emptyset$ happens. You give an example where it does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

No this is impossible.
Take any $x \in X$, as $X$ is compact $\omega (x)$ is non-empty.
Moreover it is closed, forward and backward invariant by $f$.

$\alpha(x)$ also have the same features.

Now with Zorn lemma, you can find a minimal dynamical system inside $(X,f)$ which is a closed subset $A$ in $X$ forward and backward invariant and now sub-dynamical system inside it.

Take any $x \in A$, if $\alpha(x) \cap \omega(x) = \emptyset$ you would have two non empty sub-dynamical system, which cannot be by the minimality of $A$.

I think there should be a proof without the choice axiom but I am not sure.

Comment: What about the example I gave ?

Comment: For a fix point $\alpha(x)=\omega(x)$.. In your first example $\infty$ is a fix point, in your second $0$ and $1$ are.

Comment: Oh you are right of course. I didn't see the "for all $x$"...